# Load large amounts of text in html for mobile

Tags: html, jquery, dom, web-applications, rendering

I am developing a webapp that requires the following:

1. Pages that dynamically load large amounts of text (about 30-100 printed pages) in html (using $.ajax) based on a complex function
2. Loading ALL of this text upfront. It cannot be loaded a bit at a time.
3. Showing only a small amount of text at a time.

I have been able to do this by loading all of the html into a div element (library), which I keep hidden. I use jquery to show a bit at a time in a visible div (content).

```
<div id="content">
    <ul index="1">
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
    ...
    <ul index="4">
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="library" style="display:none">
    <ul index="1">
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
    ...
    <ul index="450">
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My problem is that keeping this text in this div slows down the webpage initial loading and operation (it has animations etc). I have been able to determine that the html is loaded rather quickly, but spends a large amount of time processing (rendering?).

How can I keep this simple text library from taking so much memory. Is there some way I can keep the browser from rendering the library div besides keeping it hidden? Is there a better place to keep this content (a javascript variable for example) where I can still have access to its html elements with jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could output the hidden content in JavaScript variables rather than as HTML in the document, so that rather than this:

```
<ul index="450"> ...lots of HTML... </ul>
```

you have this:

```
<script>pages[450] = "...lots of HTML...";</script>
```

and then to make a page visible you say:

```
$('#content').html(pages[N]);
```

That way the cost of parsing each page's HTML into a DOM is only incurred when you actually show that page, rather than at load time.

Just be careful to escape the HTML that you're storing in the JavaScript string - quotes, backslashes, newlines and `</script>` spring to mind.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. It is much faster now. Thanks!